# I am terrible at my new hobby

Tags: word-property

My new hobby is putting things in alphabetical order. To my shame, it turns out I'm *terrible* at it. The list below is all wrong, but I can't see where the error is. Can you help me out? How can I alphabetize this list correctly?

```
ALDRICH · BLUES · DAY · ISRAEL · LIFTING · MALE · METAL · NEUTRINO · POLITICAL-MILITARY · RAYS
```

Comment: The dash between political and military is intended correct?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Yeah, "political-military" is meant to be one word there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason these are mis-alphabetized is that

> each of these should have a Greek letter before it.

The correct order is:

> ALPHA male; [BETA Israel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_Israel); [GAMMA rays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_ray); [DELTA blues](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/delta_blues#English); [ETA political-military](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ETA_political-military); [LAMBDA lifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_lifting); [NU metal](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nu-metal); PI day; [SIGMA-aldrich](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/); [TAU neutrino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tau_neutrino).